# How to add a Amazon polly TTS and speech marker to a 3D model build in MAYA?

Tags: node.js, three.js, amazon-polly, amazon-sumerian

We have a web application which loads a **3D model(Build in MAYA) in the browser using Three.js**. I need the following things to be added,

1. Text To Speech using Amazon Polly.
2. Get the Speech Marker from Amazon Polly and then the **3D model needs to use the Speech Marks and Whispering features** that are available in Amazon Polly.

I have googled regarding it and found https://aws.amazon.com/sumerian/features/.
In Amazon sumerian we have a feature called Sumerian Hosts, but it has predefined models.

So my question is it possible to integrate TTS with speech marks using Amazon Polly for 3D model build in MAYA using Three.js for web application build in nodejs.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please take a few minutes to look through the Help Center, specifically [`How do I ask a good question?`](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask). Be sure to include all supporting code and errors with your question. Also, consider creating a [`Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example`](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) using [snippets](https://stackoverflow.blog/2014/09/16/introducing-runnable-javascript-css-and-html-code-snippets/).

Comment: @TheJim01 It is not about coding issues, just to know about amazon polly which is new in the market and also need to know the feasibility for the above use case.

Comment: I would say this question is off-topic for Stack Overflow. SO's format is question/answer(s). Developer forums are better suited for extended discussions. Regarding your goals for this question, [please refer to the first two items here](https://stackoverflow.com/help/asking). Asking if something is feasible (basically a yes/no question) won't elicit high-quality answers. And, as I mentioned, extended discussions are considered off-topic, as is requesting off-site resources (documentation, tutorials, etc.). If you run into trouble with an implementation or concept, we would gladly try to help.

Answer (score 0):

In Amazon Sumerian you can import .obj files, .mtl files, meshes, materials, and textures using a single drag and drop. Also, Sumerian can be integrated with Amazon services like Lex, Polly etc.

To have a brief idea about the functionality that can be done using Amazon Sumerian please go through https://docs.sumerian.amazonaws.com/

I guess what you are looking for could be achieved in some other way also without using Sumerian but you can try once by importing your model in Sumerian and see whether you have the functionality of controlling the model like you wanted or not.

Do let me know if you are able to integrate Sumerian with you web app.